# Solve Any Motion Physics Problem (Equations Supplied)

Tags: code-golf, math, number

## Physics Challenge

This program should be able to solve for ANY two of the following variables the user wants to solve.

1. s (displacement)
2. v (velocity)
3. u (initial velocity)
4. a (acceleration)
5. t (time)

At start the user must choose **two** variables they want to solve for and what variables they can supply. You are limited to using the following equations.

## Equations Permitted

[image: Physics Equations]

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion)

The entrant with the least amount of code and posts the quickest will win.

## Rules

1. This is code-golf. The shortest code wins.
2. Your program must terminate in reasonable time for all reasonable inputs.
3. You are allowed to transform the equations algebraically if need be
4. The program must be able to interpret a variable of which the user cannot supply (See Example 2)

## Input Example

The program will start and ask which variable the user will like to calculate:
(s, v, u, a, t) - the user selects this via a char type or string.
It then supplies all values for the other unknowns and the program will solve for the variables.

### Example 1:

```
*What would you like to calculate? (s, v, u, a, t)*
Input: a, u     // This could also be s,v s,u, s,a v,u (ANY COMBINATION)

*Enter value for s:*
Input: 7        // The input will always be random

*Enter value for v:*
Input: 5

// Repeat for others

//program calculates

Var a = answer
Var u = answer
```

### Example 2:

```
*What would you like to calculate? (s, v, u, a, t)*
Input: a, t

*Enter value for u:*
Input: 5

*Enter value for s:*
Input: UNKNOWN

*Enter value for v:*
Input: 7

*The answers for a and t are 464 and 742*
```

## Edit

I think everyone here is overcomplicating the question. It simply asks to solve any 2 variables from the list of (s, v, u, a, t) and solve them using the equations. As the programmer you must be able to allow values to be taken for the variables that are not being solved. I will clarify that the program must be able to solve **for any** variable supplied by the user on startup. I also removed the somewhat **correct** equation s=v/t because people are becoming confused by it.

Comment: How is the input received? What format is it in? You've said it's [code-golf], but then added that solving multiple variables will increase the chance of winning - I'd have thought that would take more code and actually *reduce* their chance of winning. Probably the best way to add an extra bonus without going against the tag you've used is to add a bounty and award it to the (first?) answer that meets the extended spec.

Comment: Adding to @Gareth's remarks: can you please provide some test cases? And I don't understand Rule 3.

Comment: @Gareth You're right. I changed the challenge to be more difficult. Input is received by any way you would like it to be BUT the program must be able to calculate any case. What do you mean by which format?

Comment: @Howard Provided tests cases and removed RUle 3

Comment: The line "and also s = v/t (a simple equation to find displacement)" is just plain wrong. It's dimensionally inconsistent and contradicts the other given equations.

Comment: it should be s=v*t

Comment: @Avi No it should not.

Comment: These are not test cases but incomplete examples.

Comment: No, s=vt is wrong. It's dimensionally ok, but still contradicts the other equations -- look at Eqns 2,3,5.

Comment: Voting to hold this question until a specification is given which would allow to judge competing answers according to code-golf criteria.

Comment: @Howard I think he takes 'simple formula' as formula when acceleration is 0 . So `s=ut` OR `s=v*t` as `a=0`.

Comment: You're now asking for the program to solve underdetermined systems of equations.

Comment: There are five variables (s,u,v,a,t), and one can choose (in 10 different ways) any two of them to be expressed in terms of the other three.  If the user identifies which two are to be "solved for" (say v1, v2 to be solved for in terms of v3, v4, v5), the program can then output two equations, giving v1 and v2 in terms of v3, v4, v5. If the user additionally provides one or more consistent values for any of the variables v3, v4, v5, then the two output equations can be correspondingly simplified. It looks like a doable problem to me, and the OP has already said it's *code-golf*.

Comment: @r.e.s., you correctly observe that any two can be solved for in terms of the other three. The question currently says "the user must choose **more than two** variables they want to solve for". Surely you must agree with me that it asks to solve an underdetermined system?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Correct, but currently both examples say "What would you like to calculate? (s, v, u, a, t) Input: a, u". It seems to me that the question needs to be clarified.

Comment: you still have a contradiction between how many variables to solve for, but it is getting closer.

Answer (score 7):

### Maple, 41 chars

```
s:=i->solve({v=u+a*t,s=(u+v)*t/2,op(i)}):
```

(Formulas used: **#1** and **#3**.  These are sufficient to let Maple derive the rest.)

This defines a function `s` that takes in a set of initial conditions and solves the equations of motion for those initial values.  For example, the command:

```
> s({ u = 1, v = 2, t = 3 });
```

outputs:

```
                          {a = 1/3, s = 9/2, t = 3, u = 1, v = 2}
```

---

#### Notes:

You generally need to specify three initial values for a unique solution; if you don't provide enough, Maple will try to give you a **partial solution**:

```
> s({ u = 1, v = 2 });

                                        3 t
                          {a = 1/t, s = ---, t = t, u = 1, v = 2}
                                         2
```

(Yes, that's an ASCII art fraction there.  Even in text mode, Maple tries to typeset your math nicely.)

**No solution** is return for overspecified or otherwise unsolvable inputs; for example, `s({ u = 1, v = 2, t = 0 });` outputs nothing.

If **multiple solutions** exist, Maple will generally try to return all of them:

```
> s({ u = 1, s = 0, a = -1 });

                          {a = -1, s = 0, t = 2, u = 1, v = -1},
                          {a = -1, s = 0, t = 0, u = 1, v = 1}
```

Sometimes, the output may contain `RootOf()` expressions, as in:

```
> s({ u = 10, s = 1, a = -1 });
                                                         2
                {a = -1, s = 1, t = RootOf(2 - 20 _Z + _Z , label = _L3), u = 10,
                                               2
                 v = 10 - RootOf(2 - 20 _Z + _Z , label = _L3)}
```

As far as Maple's concerned, this is a perfectly good solution, but if you want to turn it into something readable for us mere humans, use `allvalues()`:

```
> allvalues(s({ u = 10, s = 1, a = -1 }));   
                                            1/2                 1/2
                {a = -1, s = 1, t = 10 - 7 2   , u = 10, v = 7 2   },
                                            1/2                  1/2
                {a = -1, s = 1, t = 10 + 7 2   , u = 10, v = -7 2   }
```

Alternatively, you can specify the initial conditions as floating-point values, e.g. `u = 10.0`, which will cause Maple to return purely numerical solutions instead:

```
> s({ u = 10.0, s = 1, a = -1 });

                {a = -1., s = 1., t = 0.1005050634, u = 10., v = 9.899494937},
                {a = -1., s = 1., t = 19.89949494, u = 10., v = -9.899494937}
```

Finally, note that, since Maple is a computer algebra system, it allows you to specify **arbitrary equations** in the input.  For example, if we didn't care about the specific initial velocity, but only about the change in velocity, we could just specify e.g. `v = u + 1` and get the partial solution:

```
> s({ v = u + 1 });

                {a = 1/t, s = t v - 1/2 t, t = t, u = v - 1, v = v}
```

We can even **extend the physics model** if we want, as in:

```
> s({ f = m * a, u = 0, f = 1, m = 10, t = 5 });

                {a = 1/10, f = 1, m = 10, s = 5/4, t = 5, u = 0, v = 1/2}
```

Comment: Nice. I especially like that equations 2, 4 and 5 are inferred from equations 1 and 3.

Answer (score 3):

### Golf-Basic 84, 58 characters

Executed from a TI-84 calculator

```
i`Cp`S,V,U,A,T@C=1d`U+AT@C=2d`UT+.5AT²@C=1d`"V="@C=2d`"S="
```

**Sample Run**

```
?1
?S=UNKNOWN
?V=UNKNOWN
?U=5
?A=4
?T=2
V=
              13
```

Answer (score 1):

### [GTB](http://timtechsoftware.com/?page_id=1309), 43

```
`C,S,V,U,A,T@C=1$~"V="~U+AT#~"S="~UT+.5AT²&
```

**Sample Runs**

Solve for V

```
?1
?UNKNOWN
?UNKNOWN
?5
?4
?2
V=
          13
```

Solve for S

```
?2
?UNKNOWN
?UNKNOWN
?5
?4
?2
S=
          18
```